# ModelVisual3D vs Model3DGroup

Tags: wpf, modelvisual3d

Is there any ***disadvantage*** of using ModelVisual3D over Model3DGroup. How much can the resource/performance impact possibly be?

ModelVisual3D gives me much more than Model3DGroup does but AFAIK everything that can be done with Model3DGroup can alos be done with ModelVisual3D.

So why not just always use ModelVisual3D?

Answer (score 11):

**The answer is Yes. Having many ModelVisual3ds will be orders of magnitude slower than using a Model3DGroup**

My understanding is that `ModelVisual3D` is more akin to a `UIElement`, i.e. more of a heavy weight object. MSDN says about [ModelVisual3d](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.modelvisual3d.aspx):

"Provides services and properties that are common to all visual objects, including hit-testing, coordinate transformation, and bounding-box calculations."

So if you wanted to 100 clickable 3d objects in your scene you would need 100 `ModelVisual3d` elements.

`Model3DGroup` (along with `GeometryModel3D`) on the other hand is a `Model3D`  - the building blocks of 3d models. A single `Model3D` can appear as the content for several `ModelVisual3Ds`. `Model3Ds` are more lightweight than `ModelVisual3D`.

If you wanted to construct 3d models from building blocks (like Lego), you could define several `GeometryModel3Ds`, then combine them together using a `Model3dGroup`.

Yes, the class naming is horribly confusing, and I don't think the Daniel Lehenbauer sheds any light on the subject for the average human.

Comment: I have "benchmarked" this too.. having 1000 ModelVisual3ds in a scene runs very slowly. If you use 1000 GeometryModel3Ds in a Model3DGroup is will run very smoothly